# Interaction betwen background service and front app

Tags: android, optimization, client-server, android-service

I'm currently building an app with a client-server interaction, basically the server (SocketIO, not sure it's important) is pushing data to the app, which is displaying it through a notification (if app is in background) or in the screen (if app is opened). To achieve this, i use a `Service` (notifications, app closed or hidden) and a server connection within `Activity`.

This is working fine.

But i'm not sure that it's the best way to fulfill this task, i use 2 connections and it seems not to be optimized. 
So my question is, is there a fluent, efficient, way to call Activity method (something like `getOnScreenActivity().thereIsSomethingNewBro()`) from a service, only if the app is displaying on screen ?

Thanks all.

Edit:

I managed to detect from my Service if Activity was running, but i can't find a way to get an instance of this Activity. Any clue ?

Comment: You can implement Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks to do what you want in regards to seeing if an Application is in the foreground or not.